# Why the objects are not at the same position as shown in Unity's game display when playing the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, resolution

I'm making a main menu on the scene display and game display it looks like this:[image]

But when I actually run the application Everything is shown differently as shown here:[image]

I'm new with unity so I don't know why it happens, I will be glad if you can help.